# Cannot comment to user

Tags: discussion

[regarding Astras](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23888/manthra-of-asthras)

How to message to user13155 for discussions ? It does not show up to users by tag.

Answer (score 5):

That user has been deleted (you can know that because their username is not a link, as with the other users) and therefore you can't 'message' them. Typing `@user13155` will probably work, but they won't get a notification.